# Android Studio Team collaboration

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there any way to work in collaboration in Android Studio or IntelliJ?

Yes, I know about Git, but that requires pushing and pulling which is time consuming if you want to edit very small things (a single line).

Something real time would be great.
I took a look at Floobits, just not sure if we're willing to pay for something I have no idea about.

I could see that some editors like Visual Studio Code and Atom have some real-time editing solutions, but that makes running the code a bit harder.

Can someone tell me any way to achieve this?

Comment: Currently only Floobits is possible to use.  There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-708

Comment: Sadly Floobits is online and expensive